# Insert record into mysql using json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to insert the record using json into mysql and the system could display the new record without refreshing the page.

My code is shown as below:

Part 1, the script get two values from form and convert it into json, passing them to action.php

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".submit_button").click(function() {
            var textcontent = $("#content").val();
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var dataString = {'content': textcontent, 'name': name}; 
            if (textcontent == '') {
                alert("Enter some text..");
                $("#content").focus();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#flash").show();
                $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "action.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(html){

                        $("#show").html(html);
                        $("#flash").hide();
                        $("#content").focus();
                    }  
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<div>

<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','Practical4','1234') or die('Not connected');

$database=mysqli_select_db($conn,'Practical4') or die('Database Not connected');

$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "select * from hotel where name='$id'";
$data=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

    $name=$rows['name'];
    $price=$rows['price'];
    $duetime=$rows['dueTime'];
    $address=$rows['location'];
}
?>
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<h3>Add Comment for <?php echo $name;?><h3>
<textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="content" id="content" maxlength="145" >

</textarea><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" hidden > <br>

<input type="submit" value="Add Comment" name="submit" class="submit_button"/>

</form>
</div> 

<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$username="Practical4"; 
$password="1234"; 
$db_name="Practical4"; 
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from comment where name='$name'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
   $json[] = $row[1];
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo implode('<br />', $json);

?> 

<div class="space" ></div>
<div id="flash"></div>
<div id="show" ></div>
```

Part2, action.php, which insert the record into mysql database.

```
<?php

$DBServer = 'localhost'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'Practical4';
$DBPass   = '1234';
$DBName   = 'Practical4';

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$v1="'" . $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['content']) . "'";
$v2="'" . $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "'";

$sql="INSERT INTO comment (content,name) VALUES ($v1,$v2)";

if($conn->query($sql) === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $last_inserted_id = $conn->insert_id;
  $affected_rows = $conn->affected_rows;
  echo '<div class="showbox">'.$v1.'</div>';
}

?>
```

So far the code can insert new data, but it won't display the new record dynamically without refreshing page. Any idea to fix that?

Comment: Is there any element exists with id `show`?

Comment: You can return the updated data from `action.php` and update the DOM.

Comment: add full html in your question

Comment: @KristerAndersson OP already doing that.

Comment: Full HTML is added@AwladLiton

Comment: I think the system didn't go to success function in script, any idea why it didn't?

Comment: @user1805430 Did you see errors on developer console?

Comment: no error is indicated in developer console @RahilWazir

Comment: Change your `dataType` to `html` since this is what is expected as a return value from the ajax request.

Comment: Thanks! If I insist on using json, what kinds of changes should I make?

Comment: Then you should return a json encoded response: `print json_encode(array('html' => '<div class="showbox">'.$v1.'</div>'));` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `dataType` to `html` since this parameter tells the server what kind of response it will accept in return:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "action.php",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: 'html', 
  cache: true,
  success: function(data){
    $("#show").html(data);
    $("#flash").hide();
    $("#content").focus();
  }  
});
```

In the above case the return value should be plain html:

```
print '<div class="showbox">' . $v1 . '</div>';
```

You then add it to your page using:

```
$('#show').html(data);
```

If you still would like to use `json` you could encode your response using something like this:

```
print json_encode(array('html' => '<div class="showbox">' . $v1 . '</div>'));
```

Then you would need to parse this value:

```
$("#show").html(data.html);
```

In the above example it seems clearer to name the `success` functions argument to something like `data` since it won't contain just html in the case.

Comment: Thanks! I can now get value from developer console, but still couldn't display the new record in the current page. Besides, How can I decode this echo json_encode(array('html' => '<div class="showbox">'.$v1.'</div>')); to display content only?

Comment: @user1805430 - You should be able to access the `html` part of the return value using `html.html`, isn't this working? Try echoing the entire `html` and make sure so its really an object.

Comment: Also, if I were you I would use firefox and firebug to get a better view on what's happening during the request.